# What is the analog of 'Bind' in .NET Standard and where do I find it?

Tags: .net-core, bind

I'm porting an application from .NET Framework 4.5 to .NET Standard and there are many properties an classes decorated with the 'Bind' attribute.  What is the analog in .NET Standard and what assembly/package do I need to pull in?

```
[Bind(Exclude = "Fund,Audit")]
public class FundTrade : IFundRef
{
    /// <summary>
}
```

Doesn't compile in .NET Standard but builds just fine in a .NET Framework project.  "Type of namespace 'Bind' could not be found (are you missing an assembly reference)"

Comment: Can you cut and paste a sample?  MVC 6 is not a library, while .Net Core is a runtime with a framework (series of libraries).

Comment: Hopefully the edits make the issue more clear.

Comment: A .netstandard project is useful because it can run on many different kind of operating systems and project types.  [Bind] is not standard, it requires aspcore.net and isn't going to work on, say, a phone or a winforms app.  You'll need to either partition your code better or acknowledge that this library is only going to work on aspcore and change the target.